# How do you target desktop mode running Lighthouse in a pipeline

Tags: performance-testing, lighthouse, lighthouse-ci, playwright-lighthouse

I'm running lighthouse for performance testing in a pipeline:

Github workflow:

```js
    - name: Run Lighthouse on urls and upload data to private lhci server
      if: always()
      uses: treosh/lighthouse-ci-action@v9
      with:
        configPath: ./lighthouserc.yml
```

config file:

```js
ci:
  collect:
    # Puppeteer is used to login
    puppeteerScript: puppeteer-script.js
    puppeteerLaunchOptions:
      args:
        - '--no-sandbox'
        - '--headless'
        - '--ignore-certificate-errors'
    numberOfRuns: 1
    settings:
      onlyCategories:
        - accessibility
        - best-practices
        - performance
  assert:
    preset: lighthouse:recommended
    assertions:
      categories:performance:
        - error
        - minScore: .5
      categories:accessibility:
        - error
        - minScore: .85
      categories:best-practices:
        - error
        - minScore: .8
```

THere's a puppeteer script used for login.

I'm not sure how to set up Lighthouse to run the performance tests in desktop mode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.